# How do I set the wrapper to automatically vertically center within the body?

Tags: html, css, center, vertical-alignment

I haven't set a height to the body - I just want the wrapper to automatically vertically center within the body. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What `position` are you using? absolute/relative/fixed ?
what kind of width? % or px ?? Would need more info ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a couple wrapping `<div>` elements and using `display: table`, `display: table-cell`, and `vertical-align: middle`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonypawks/KPufS/1/)